# Cant store information on DB from Laravel form

Tags: php, laravel

I have this application using Laravel and im trying to register some information from the Form Class to my DB through the store method in the controller, but for some reason it throws me some error. I cant even print the request coming from the form, as usual. Can someone point me a possible mistake tht i am making? I am new to Laravel

This is my form on a view called create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')



    <p><b>Register your house</b></p>


            {!! Form::open(['method'=>'post', 'action'=>'AdminHouseController@store']) !!}

                {!! Form::text('house_address', null,['placeholder'=>'House Address']) !!}

                <input type="hidden" name="house_admin" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}">

                {!! Form::number('nflatmates', null, ['placeholder'=>'How many flatmates']) !!}

                {!! Form::submit('Register', ['class'=>'ui-btn buttonDefault']) !!}

            {!! Form::close() !!}




@stop
```

This is my controller AdminHouseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\House;
use App\User;

class AdminHouseController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){




    }


    public function create($role_id){

        if($role_id == 1){

            return view('admin.house.create');

        }else{

            return redirect('home');

        }

    }


    public function store(Request $request){

        House::create($request->all());

        return redirect('home');

    }

    public function show($id){

    }

    public function edit($id){

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){

    }

    public function destroy($id){

    }
}
```

And this is my router file web.php

```
use App\User;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/house/{role_id}', 'AdminHouseController@create')->name('house');

Route::post('store', [
    'uses' => 'AdminHouseController@store'
]);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: As I am using jQuery Mobile it only displays error loading page. In The console it says error 500. The curious is that when I use return $request->all() it doesn't display me anything. I believe it should

Comment: Check the last error message in the `storage/logs/laravel.log` file

Comment: Great, found the mistake from the log file. Thanks a million @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be missing the {{ csrf_field() }} in the form this used to protect the form from tampering